# How to save the properties of UILable in UIView in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

import UIKit

class AboutView: UIView{

```
@IBOutlet var aboutView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var studioTXT: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var closeBTN: UIButton!

var studioTxtTo : CGFloat

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    initializeViews()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    initializeViews()
}

private func initializeViews(){
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("AboutView", owner: self)
    addSubview(aboutView)

    studioTxtTo = self.studioTXT.frame.origin.y
    self.studioTXT.frame.origin.y = self.studioTXT.frame.origin.y + 55
}

@IBAction func onIn(_ sender: Any) {
    in()
}

func in(){

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {

    self.studioTXT.frame.origin.y = self.studioTxtTo

    }, completion: { _ in
        //
    })
}
```

}

i need to save origin Y peropertie of my label to create animation, but get error in super.init(frame: frame) and super.init(coder: aDecoder) for studioTxtTo

Comment: Property 'self.studioTxtTo' not initialized at super.init call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide initial value for studioTxtTo, for example change your definition to:

```
var studioTxtTo : CGFloat = 0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an instance property `studioTxtTo`. You *must* give this instance property an initial value, somehow, by the time your initializer completes initialization. As the error message rightly tells you, you are failing to do that (in both initializers). Do it.